# What is the most appropriate word in this case?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

When you see an error in an app or in a software, what is the most appropriate word for the title: "Warning", "Caution", "Attention", "Beware"?

I saw many examples with these words on the Internet (especially for "Caution" with a yellow sign) but I didn't find a final answer when the context is about to show an error to a user. I would use "Warning" but I'm not sure, may be it's out of context.

Comment: *Caution*, *Warning*, and *Beware* are only helpful if you're making the user aware of a threat *in advance*. If the error already occurred and no additional damage can be done by the user taking the wrong action, then there is no use or place for warnings.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I want to show a "warning" title I must use Caution, Warning or Beware. And "Attention" if the error already occurred?

Comment: That's the way is go. And I'd stick with plain *warning*. You could use *caution*, though it's more likely to draw attention to the wording than the threat. And *beware* would be a bit silly.

Comment: Ok, I'll use "warning" and "attention" in the right cases. Thank you very much. :)